# PHP flush function causing weird characters on the screen

Tags: php, flush

After so much trouble I find out that when I use the flush function in my PHP mail script then I get garbage or dump characters on browser like below.

[image]

The code is below

```
if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo "<br><font color=darkgreen>[$num successful send to $to]</font> ";
    // flush();
    return true;
}
```

If I comment that flush line then out is simple English but I uncomment that the whole page the text looks like garbage.

Now is that a PHP problem, browser problem or server problem?

If I use the same script from the shell, I mean execute inside the shell terminal then I can see the HTML output. But it does not work in browsers.

Comment: have you tried ob_start() and ob_end_flush() instead?

Comment: What browser are you seeing it on? Already tried another browser? Seems like the browser uses the wrong character set.

Comment: I tried all browses and it was same

Comment: Running into the same thing, the solution unfortunately didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I had to turn

```
zlib_compression off
```

in my `php.ini` settings file.

(What does that mean and why did it work?. I had been trying this for 1 year but could not resolve the problem but now it worked.)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was to use `ob_start` before my `echo` statements, then use `ob_end_flush` and `flush` after them:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    ob_start();
    echo "$i";
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```